# Yii filter not showing up in CGridView

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm having problems filtering my CGridView. I am doing this all in studProg/view:
Here I create CGridView based on another table/model called kurs, I get the data and all that is ok. Now I want to be able to get key-value from another table and list them in filter options in my CGrid. However, dropdown doesn't show up. Why?

Here are important parts of my code:

studProg/view CGridView body:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'kursData',
'dataProvider'=>$kursDataProvider,
'columns'=>array(
    array(
        'header' => 'Studijska godina',
        'type' => 'raw',
        'filter' => $model->getStudijskeGodine(),
        'value' => '$data->stud_god_god'
    ),etc..
```

and from StudProg model:

```
public function getStudijskeGodine()
{
    $query = 'select god from stud_god';
    $rezultat = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll();
    $spisak = CHtml::listData($rezultat, 'god' , 'god');

    return $spisak;
}
```

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listData-detail
listData expects something else, then what you are giving it.

Answer (score 0):

Configure `filter` in Grid View first. Remember that custom filters always works with `name` property.

```
        <?php
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id'=>'kursData',
        'dataProvider'=>$kursDataProvider,
        'filter'=>$model,    //Need this property to get the filter.
        'columns'=>array(
            array(
                'header' => 'Studijska godina',
                'name'=>'stud_god_god', //Need this filter
                'type' => 'raw',
                'filter' => $model->getStudijskeGodine(),
                'value' => '$data->stud_god_god'
            )
```

Comment: Field stud_god_god is not from this model. It's from the table I get with my dataProvider. What now? That's why I get error in 'name' part with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have more than one table involved you need to configure relation between them in your model in order to use it in the grid for filtering. As far as I am aware at least.

You can find more information about it here:
[declaring relationships in Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#declaring-relationship)